# How do I change my grid

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently generating a grid dynamically in JQuery for my spelling game. At the moment the grid is a 6x6, because it deals with 3 letter words only.

The problem is I need to be able to change the amount of rows and columns for future development (adding bigger words etc).

Ideally I want to be able to change the rows and columns in HTML so that less experienced colleagues can change it's size when I am not there.

I have been looking at forms to take the data in HTML and pass it through to the JQuery, but I'm not sure if i get how I would do it with the JQuery I am using to create the grid as I am creating it from the words I have stored in a list in the body.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Here is the script that generates the grid...

```
var listOfWords = [];
var rndWord = [];
var counter = 0;
var ul = document.getElementById("wordlist");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < ul.children.length; ++i) {

    listOfWords.push({
        "name": ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-word"),
        "pic": ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-pic"),
        "audio": ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-audio")
     });
}

var chosenWords = [];
var copylist = listOfWords.slice();

for (var x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (copylist.length));
    chosenWords.push(copylist[rand].name);
    copylist.splice(rand, 1);
    if (chosenWords.length < 12) {
        chosenWords.push('   ');
     }

 }

var shuffledWords = [];
shuffledWords = chosenWords.sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random()
});

 var guesses = {};
var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.className = 'tablestyle';
var wordsPerRow = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < shuffledWords.length - 1; i += wordsPerRow) {

    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = i; j < i + wordsPerRow; ++j) {
        var word = shuffledWords[j];
        guesses[word] = [];

        for (var k = 0; k < word.length; ++k) {
            var cell = document.createElement('td');


            $(cell).addClass('drop-box').attr('data-word', word).attr('data-letter', word[k]);
            cell.textContent = word[k];

            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }

    tbl.appendChild(row);
}

$(".container").append(tbl);
```

I store the words and the attached sounds and pics like this...

```
    <li data-word="mum" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig2.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/5/e/7/f/1195445022768793934Gerald_G_Lady_Face_Cartoon_1.svg.med.png"></li>

    <li data-word="cat" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/bugsbunny2.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/c/9/9/5/119543969236915703Gerald_G_Cartoon_Cat_Face.svg.med.png"></li>

    <li data-word="dog" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/2/c/0/1195440948271207911zeimusu_spotty_dog.svg.med.png"></li>

    <li data-word="bug" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck2.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/4/b/4/2/1216180545881311858laurent_scarabe.svg.med.png"></li>

    <li data-word="rat" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/bugsbunny1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/C/j/X/e/k/D/mouse-md.png"></li>

    <li data-word="dad" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/a/6/6/119544474191128182Gerald_G_Man_Face_6_-_World_Label.svg.med.png"></li>
```

Comment: Just cause I'm curios, why don't you use jQuery that much for in your code ? You are not using the full libary or even selectors. Your `document.getelementbyId` call could be simplified with `$('#wordlist')`

Comment: I'm quite new to it. I try to use it as much as possible @EvilP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list of words are all 3 characters long then you could generate 3x3, 6x6, 9x9, etc which is kind of limiting.  If the the number of characters for the words in your list vary, then you could insure that at each row the words selected randomly add up to whatever the grid size is. So for a 10x10 grid for example, we choose a length at random where length<=10.  Say it is 5. Next word could be two to five characters long, etc.  You should store the words in a dictionary/hash based on their length and another hash so you know if the word has already been used.

Comment: Ye thats what I want. It is only 3 char words at the moment. How would I do that? @Jay

Comment: it's really the number of permutations of 3 or more character words whose length adds up to a constant. You can generate these permutations based on the length and then choose one at random each row

Comment: say we have randomly chosen a gridsize of 20

Comment: you choose from the list of words such that length of first word is <=17

Comment: you subtract 20 from the length of the word say it was 7. You have 13 left, or really 10 since you want to insure last word fits

Comment: once you get down to 3 to 6, you simply choose a word with length 3 to 6

Comment: or you could randomly say if there is 7 to 9 then choose a 7 or 9 character word for the last word in the row

Comment: this way you don't have to generate permutations

Comment: Here's how you could set up the data structure: var words = {}. Then just push all the words into the object based on their length for each word: words['length'+word.length] = []; words['length'+word.length].push(word)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/TqGPb/5/ Any chance you could show me in this fiddle? @Jay

Comment: That is what I need because at the moment when I add a four letter word it overlaps into the wrong place

Comment: Since the grid is currently sized<=6, the approach I'm talking about will only work for words of length=3 and length=6 (I can't think of words of length 2 that would match a picture..). Increase the size of the grid (preferably to a variable amount>6) and store the words in an object based on the length (create more words inside the UL) before starting

Comment: It will only be for words from 3-5 characters anyway. Could you send me a fiddle that shows me what you mean though as I am having trouble to understand what you mean @Jay

Comment: make the grid size bigger then because a 6x6 grid size implies only words of length 3 (since they're only 3-5 characters) which you have already done

Comment: I don't know which bit to change to do that though @Jay

Comment: Change the bit that generates the 6x6 table so that it is larger than 6x6. Also change how you are storing the words so that you can quickly choose a word based on the length and shuffle on length then on the word. It would be easier for me to write this from scratch than to try to edit it. Did you write the code or was it given to you?

Comment: It was given to me so I don't really understand it. I would ideally want it in JQuery. The thing is I need to store the words in HTML because colleuges will be putting new words in that don't know how to use JQuery. @Jay

Comment: since you didn't write it, my recommendation is to keep the html content, extend it with some more words of different length and write the javascript code yourself from scratch. I would use jquery as well simply because it will save you some time and energy and result in code that will work on more browsers

Comment: Im gunna do that today. Can you do me one favour and tell me why I can't change the wordPerRow? @Jay